# What does asm("stw r4, %0": "=m" (returnCode)) mean? Nios 2

Tags: assembly, nios

```
asm("stw r4, %0": "=m" (returnCode))
```

The above call is made from c to a Nios2 where return code is variable in C.
I get stw stores from one register to another or from memory, but I'm not sure what the %0 or the "=m" represent.

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is GCC inline assembly, so with that in mind...
And note...  My GCC inline days are long behind me, but...

`stw` The instruction to be executed

`r4`  Looks like the name of a register

`%0`  Refers to the list of variables/registers/parameters after the colon

`=m`  Is a constraint. `=m` means constrain operations on `%0` to memory writes, if I'm readng the docs correctly.

See [here](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html) for better explanations of GCC inline assembly.